# Size of figures in knitr with patchwork or cowplot

Tags: r, knitr, cowplot, patchwork

I have a large number of figures which I would like to present in a single column in a document created with knitr. The number of figures can vary, so I created a function to combine all figures using `patchwork::wrap_plots` (`cowplot::plot_grid` is an alternative, but has the same issues described below). MWE:

```
library(patchwork)
library(tidyverse)

plots <- lapply(1:10, function(x) data.frame(A = rnorm(1:100, 0, 1), B = rnorm(1:100, 0, 1)) %>% 
                  ggplot(., aes(x = A, y = B)) + 
                  geom_point() +
                  coord_equal())

wrap_plots(plots, ncol = 1)
```

By default, this creates tiny plots. (Leaving out `coord_equal` leads to plots of the same height, but with full page width):

[image: Plot with patchword::wrap_plots]

Using knitr's chunk option `fig.height` (but not `fig.width`) it is possible to scale up the plots. However, this leads to very large margins above and below the entire plot.

I have found a number of solution for controlling the size of `patchwork` or `cowplot` plots (e.g., using `cowplot::save_plot`). However, none of these seem applicable to documents created with knitr.

Preferably, I would like figures to automatically have the same width as text in the knitr output, without excessive margins.

Comment: If you're using `coord_equal()`, you need to set both `fig.width` and `fig.height` to appropriate values. E.g., if your figures are approximately square, and you have a column of 10 figures, then `fig.height` needs to be ten times larger than `fig.width`.

Comment: @ClausWilke Thanks for the tip, you should put this in an answer